# Getting error trying to test service on Spring project with junit

Tags: java, spring, junit, spring-webflow

I am trying to run my first test with junit on a Spring Web Flow Project from within Eclipse and also from the console with mvn test and but give me the same error.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [WEB-INF/spring/root-config.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [WEB-INF/spring/root-config.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

I checked and I do have this file in the location so I dont know why Eclipse and Maven is not finding it.  Can someone please help me out... below is my test classs

```
package org.uftwf.memberinquiry.text;

import junit.framework.Assert;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.uftwf.memberinquiry.model.MemberInquiryInformation;
import org.uftwf.memberinquiry.model.MemberRequest;
import org.uftwf.memberinquiry.service.MemberInquiryService;


@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:/WEB-INF/spring/root-config.xml")
public class TestApp {

    @Autowired
    private MemberInquiryService service;

    @Test
    public void testgetMemeberRequestInformation() {

        MemberRequest inMemberRequest = new MemberRequest();

        MemberInquiryInformation testInfo = service.getMemeberRequestInformation(inMemberRequest);

        inMemberRequest.setRequestor("cpilling04@aol.com.dev");


        Assert.assertEquals(testInfo.getFirst_Name(), "Christine");
        Assert.assertEquals(testInfo.getLast_Name(), "Pillings");
    }

}
```

Comment: The error is pretty self explanatory, why are you trying to load up the test context from a specific classpath folder?

Just make it relative to your test class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated to the up to date spring-test and junit and now everything is find

Answer (score 0):

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {classpath:spring/root-config.xml})
```

or create

```
TestApp-context.xml
```

Comment: Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@39e4853f] to prepare test instance [org.uftwf.memberinquiry.text.TestApp@49e808ca]
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [WEB-INF/spring/root-config.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [WEB-INF/spring/root-config.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist

Comment: Just copy my variant WITHOUT [WEB-INF/spring/

Comment: And one more question, root config is applucation config for your application ? If yes, create test config in test/resources folder and import your application config

Comment: yes but its the one for for the web project. how would the one in test resources load the one in web-inf?

Comment: i moved them to the test/resource and it looks bettter.  I am now gettng java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/Assume$AssumptionViolatedException

Comment: U have no some libs (test libs) in class path, check and fix it.

Answer (score 0):

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:WEB-INF/spring/root-config.xml")
```

When you start the path by /, it is understood, as an absolute path.