# Spring JUnit ContextConfiguration class path resource cannot be opened

Tags: spring, junit, spring-boot, spring-test

I am using the latest version of Spring-Boot (spring boot starter web and test), in a gradle project. And this older unit test I use to have is no longer working.

The XML context file is located under src/test/resources/myTestContext.xml. But I get the error below when I try to run this as a Junit test in Eclipse (mars 4.5)

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"/myTestContext.xml"})
public class MyTest extends AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests{
....


Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [myTestContext.xml] 
cannot be opened because it does not exist at     
org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:172) ~[spring-core-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
```

Comment: is `src/test/resources` in your classpath?

Comment: in eclipse, if I go to project -> properties -> java build path, I see src/test/resources listed.

Comment: have you tried it without the "/"?

Comment: Remove starting / and add classpath: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64737566/715269